# ImportError: no module named py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe

I get this error when I try to use one of the py2exe samples with py2exe.

```
File "setup.py", line 22, in ?
   import py2exe
ImportError: no module named py2exe
```

I've installed py2exe with the installer, and I use python 2.6. I have downloaded the correct installer from the site (The python 2.6 one.)

My path is set to C:\Python26 and I can run normal python scripts from within the command prompt.

Any idea what to do?

Thanks.

Edit: I had python 3.1 installed first but removed it afterwards. Could that be the problem?

Comment: have you installed `setup_tools` ?

Comment: No, I haven't installed that. Does py2exe requires that?

Comment: Try `python --version` to make absolutely sure you're running Python 2.6.

Comment: It shows python 2.4.3. I've never installed that though, probably came with my computer. Is there a way to change the default python version?

Comment: I think it does require `setup_tools`. On my computer, I have it installed and I generated an exe yesterday without errors. Try to install it.

Comment: I've installed setup_tools. How should I use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like something has installed Python 2.4.3 behind your back, and set that to be the default.

Short term, try running your script explicitly with Python 2.6 like this:

```
c:\Python26\python.exe setup.py ...
```

Long term, you need to check your system PATH (which it sounds like you've already done) and your file associations, like this:

```
C:\Users\rjh>assoc .py
.py=Python.File

C:\Users\rjh>ftype Python.File
Python.File="C:\Python26\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

Simply removing Python 2.4.3 might be a mistake, as presumably something on your system is relying on it.  Changing the PATH and file associations to point to Python 2.6 *probably* won't break whatever thing that is, but I couldn't guarantee it.

Comment: The short time solution worked but it couldn't find msvcp90dll when it tried to search for dlls. I downloaded a copy from the internet and placed it in the C:\Python26/DLLs directory and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Seems like you need to download proper [py2exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/) distribution.

Check out if your `c:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\` contains `py2exe` folder.

Comment: What should one do if c:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\ does not contain the py2exe folder? ;)

Comment: Go to http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/ and download the version corresponding to your version of python.

Answer (score 3):

If you have any other versions of Python installed, it may be that another Python version is the default Python. Could this be the case? I believe the default Python installation is determined from a registry setting.

Comment: Python 2.4.3 is the default. Is there any way to change it to 2.6.2?

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue and I just managed to get it solved - so I thought I would share my solution.

It turned out that my installation of CollabNet SVN contained an old version of Python that interfered with my recent Python2.7 installation.

Replacing CollabNet SVN with VisualSVN (including a couple of reboots) did the trick. I know this is not a "pretty" solution, as it caused me to uninstall CollabNet SVN - a prettier solution might have been doing modifications to the PATH env. variable... However, I am now able to use py2exe :)

Answer (score 0):

For the record, my very similar problem was caused by using a *Cygwin* prompt. Using as standard *cmd.exe* shell instead worked (given all paths and correctly installed versions of python).

This was because (stupid me) the Cygwin install had pulled down it's own version of `/usr/bin/python`. I equally fixed it by adding the Windows installed python location to the head of the Cygwin `PATH=/cygdrive/c/Python27:$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install the py2exe module globally, perhaps you might have installed to a virtualenv. I had the same problem, installing the module globally fixed the problem