# Invalid command 'py2exe'

Tags: python, py2exe

I have python 2.5 and 2.6 installed. I'm running my project on 2.6. 
First I had py2exe for 2.5 installed but it didn't work so I installed py2exe for 2.6 and deleted the other version but then the module wasn't found. Now I changed the sys path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('F:\Program Files\Python26\Lib\site-packages\py2exe')
from build_exe import py2exe 
from distutils.core import setup

setup( 
 name =...
```

When i type into the console: path\setup.py py2exe
I get "error: invalid command 'py2exe'"

EDIT: I changed the path to 'F:/Program Files/Python26/Lib/site-packages/py2exe' with correct slashes.
Console looks like this:

```
E:\Eclipse Workspace\...\src>setup.py py2exe
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
or: setup.py --help-commands
or: setup.py cmd --help
error: invalid command 'py2exe'
```

Comment: Always use raw strings or escaped backslashes for Windows paths.

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling the 2.6 version - maybe some common components got removed when you removed the old version.

Comment: Tried reinstalling and backslashes. It still says "invalid command py2exe"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
sys.path.append('F:\Program Files\Python26\Lib\site-packages\py2exe')
```

A backslash (`\`) is an [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) and interperted in a special way by almost all programming languages, including Python.

It's unfortunate that DOS (And by extension Windows) also uses the backslash as a directory separator instead of a a slash. [There is a bit of history behind this](https://superuser.com/questions/176388/why-does-windows-use-backslashes-for-paths-and-unix-forward-slashes)...

In any case, you have a few options:

Use slashes. Python will convert them to backslashes internally.

```
d = 'C:/Program Files/'
```

Use two backslahes, this will escape the backslashes and insert a single backslashes.

```
d = 'C:\\Program Files\\'
```

Use a "raw" string which doesn't interpret escape character. Do this by adding a `r` before the string.

```
d = r'C:\Program Files\'
```

I personally prefer the first solution. But I've seen the other two being used quite a bit too. Note that this also works the other way around, so if you use backslashes Python will convert it to slashes on UNIX and Linux systems.

As a free bonus hint, this may also be a good place to point out the [os.path.join()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) function :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried 'F:/Program Files/Python26/Lib/site-packages/py2exe' and also \\ but I still get the same error. When I add a slash at the end 'F:/Program Files/Python26/Lib/site-packages/py2exe/' it says no module named build_exe. Any idea why python doesn't find py2exe? Pygame is located in the same directory and I can import it without problems.

Comment: Normally you don't need to append the path if it's in site-packages. Did you install both Python and py2exe using the installers? In any case, You'll need to add ``F:/Program Files/Python26/Lib/site-packages/`` to your path, without the py2exe.

Comment: Yes, everything installed with installer. With F:/Program Files/Python26/Lib/site-packages/ I get "Import error: No module named build_exe. \site-packages\py2exe contains build_exe.py so I have no idea why python's complaining again.

Comment: Start python from the commandline, ``import sys``, and ``print sys.path``. ``F:/Program Files/Python26/Lib/site-packages/`` should be there. If it's not, something is wrong with your installation. You're also using the wrong import syntax, reverse ``py2exe`` and ``build_exe``. AFAIK you should also just use ``import py2exe``.

Comment: F:/Program Files/Python26/Lib/site-packages/ is listed under sys.path so I removed that append line. I copied `from py2exe.build_exe import py2exe` from a python book -> error:no module named py2exe.build_exe. Then I tried `import py2exe` -> error: no module named py2exe. `from build_exe import py2exe` -> error: no module named build_exe. `from py2exe import build_exe` -> error: no module named py2exe.

Comment: Neither does `import build_exe` or `import py2exe.build_exe` work.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271337/importerror-no-module-named-py2exe The console was using my python 2.5 installation. Thanks for your help Carpetsmoker!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple.

Add install.

So instead of

> setup.py py2exe

write

> setup.py py2exe install

and it works