# Something is not going right with my py2exe installation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to use py2exe on a completed code, but something is not going right with my py2exe installation. I am getting the error below:

I am running below version of Python along with py2exe

```
>>>>>Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.7-64 *

>>>>>Collecting py2exe
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/16/19bd8b59db4a61ff003aee258efd86a0aca050718435b1f54592ac870235/py2exe-0.9.2.2-py33.py34-none-any.whl (270kB)
     |¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦| 276kB 819kB/s
Installing collected packages: py2exe
Successfully installed py2exe-0.9.2.2
```

Please Help

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sip
setup(options={'py2exe':{'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True}}, 
    windows=['INCSrc.py'], zipfile = None)
```

> Error: Importing py2exe fails

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Python Projects\Final\setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    import py2exe
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py2exe'
```

Comment: Make sure the you're installing `py2exe` to the same python installation you're running this from

Comment: @JammyDodger how can I change the installation path .. It seems py2exe is inside    c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (0.9.2.2)    and  my code is in   C:\Users\Desktop\Python Projects\Final\setup.py?

Comment: @Gary Just run "Command Prompt (cmd)" as Administrator and then try to install "py2exe" and then import module.

Comment: @UrviSoni I just tried running as Admin but no luck                                                              Requirement already satisfied: py2exe in c:\users\gsingh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (0.9.2.2)                                                                                                                                   import py2exe
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py2exe'

Comment: @Gary just check this You will find your solution:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271337/importerror-no-module-named-py2exe

Comment: @UrviSoni I checked this one but seems its for Python 2.X and  I am running 3.X

Answer (score 0):

Open your CMD prompt command and try:

```
pip install py2exe
```

or in Conda prompt:

```
conda install py2exe
```

To check all installed modules:

```
pip freeze
```

If you're using Pycharm you can Go File -> Settings -> Project: PycharmProjects -> Project Interpreter

And install manually all modules you need.

Good luck!

Comment: I tried these but no luck.. Note: I a, using Sublime Text Editor and Still getting the same error... It's not working